# Connect to a device using Modbus-RTU protocol with Qt/C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt

my problem is I don't know why my code stop receiving data from a connection to the controller.

**Situation:** I'm writing a Qt program to connect and get data from a device. The device uses Modbus-RTU protocol with baudrates 9600, Even Parity, 8 databits, 1 stopbit to transfer data on RS-485. My Qt program use QSerialPort class to communicate with the device. In the first time I start the program, I can receive reply from the device after I sent a binary packet. But from the second time, my program doesn't receive anything, even I sent a lot of the same packets above. Please check my code below for easier understanding:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSerialPort/qserialport.h>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    fstream fs;

    QSerialPort qsp;
    qsp.setPortName("COM2");
    qsp.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    qsp.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    qsp.setParity(QSerialPort::EvenParity);
    qsp.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    qsp.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

    if (qsp.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
        QByteArray qbaDataSend;
        qbaDataSend.resize(8);
        qbaDataSend[0] = 0x01;
        qbaDataSend[1] = 0x03;
        qbaDataSend[2] = 0x00;
        qbaDataSend[3] = 0x00;
        qbaDataSend[4] = 0x00;
        qbaDataSend[5] = 0x0A;
        qbaDataSend[6] = 0xC5;
        qbaDataSend[7] = 0xCD;
        cout << endl << "Byte wrote: " <<qbaDataSend.toHex().toStdString() << endl << "Length: " << qsp.write(qbaDataSend) << endl;

        fs.open("Data.txt", ios_base::app | ios_base::out);

        fs << qbaDataSend.toHex().toStdString() << endl;

        fs << "Length: " << qbaDataSend.toStdString().length() << endl << endl;
        fs.close();
        qsp.flush();
        while(true){
            _sleep(3000);
            do {
                QByteArray qbaDataRead = qsp.readAll();

                fs.open("Data.txt", ios_base::app | ios_base::out);
                cout << qbaDataRead.toHex().toStdString() << endl;
                fs << qbaDataRead.toHex().toStdString() << endl;
                cout << "Length: " << qbaDataRead.toStdString().length() << endl << endl;
                fs << "Length: " << qbaDataRead.toStdString().length() << endl << endl;
                fs.close();
            }
            while(qsp.waitForReadyRead(3000));

            cout << endl << "Byte wrote: " <<qbaDataSend.toHex().toStdString() << endl << "Length: " << qsp.write(qbaDataSend) << endl;
            qsp.write(qbaDataSend, 8);
            fs.open("Data.txt", ios_base::app | ios_base::out);

            fs << qbaDataSend.toHex().toStdString() << endl;

            fs << "Length: " << qbaDataSend.toStdString().length() << endl << endl;
            fs.close();
            qsp.flush();
        }
    }

    cout << "Out" << endl;

    qsp.close();
    cout << "Error: " << qsp.errorString().toStdString() << endl;
    cout << "Close" << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

Here's the result I got:

```
01030000000ac5cd
Length: 8


Length: 0

0103140000001b0000000000000000ffb2000400040000b49e
Length: 25

01030000000ac5cd
Length: 8


Length: 0

01030000000ac5cd
Length: 8


Length: 0

01030000000ac5cd
Length: 8
```

Did I miss something in my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use the debugger and see what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

> Did I miss something in my code?

At the very least you missed error checking.

It's also hard to tell whether your device may be malfunctioning or not.

Other nitpicks: The `flush` is unnecessary since the `waitForReadyRead` performs an implicit flush. The `_sleep` is unnecessary as well: the last, failing `waitForReadyRead` will wait 3 seconds.  It's questionable whether you wish to be re-opening the log file - perhaps you only wish to `flush()` it? Finally, do not use `<QtModule/QClass>` includes - they defer project configuration errors to link time. Use `<QClass>` includes only, or to include the entire Qt module use `<QtModule>`.

The example you posted is somewhat convoluted, so perhaps this easier-to-read version with error checking will make it possible for you to figure what's wrong:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/serial-blocking-45369860
#include <QtSerialPort>

template <class T> bool hasError(const QIODevice & d) {
   return qobject_cast<const T *>(&d) && static_cast<const T &>(d).error() != T::NoError;
}

void chkError(const QIODevice & d) {
   if (hasError<QFile>(d) || hasError<QSerialPort>(d))
      qFatal("I/O Error on %s: %s", d.objectName().toLocal8Bit().constData(),
             d.errorString().toLocal8Bit().constData());
}

void logData(QTextStream & log, const QByteArray & data) {
   log << data.toHex() << "\nLength: " << data.size() << "\n\n";
   log.flush();
   chkError(*log.device());
}

void transmit(QSerialPort & port, const QByteArray & data, QTextStream & log) {
   port.write(data);
   qDebug() << "\nWrote" << data.size() << ":" << data.toHex().constData();
   chkError(port);
   logData(log, data);
}

void receive(QSerialPort & port, QTextStream & log) {
   auto data = port.readAll();
   qDebug() << "\nRead" << data.size() << ":" << data.toHex().constData();
   chkError(port);
   logData(log, data);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

   QFile logFile("Data.txt");
   if (!logFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text))
      qFatal("Can't open the log file: %s", logFile.errorString().toLocal8Bit().constData());
   QTextStream log(&logFile);

   QSerialPort port;
   port.setPortName("COM2");
   port.setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
   port.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
   port.setParity(QSerialPort::EvenParity);
   port.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
   port.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

   if (!port.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
      qFatal("Can't open the serial port: %s", port.errorString().toLocal8Bit().constData());

   logFile.setObjectName("Log File");
   port.setObjectName("Serial Port");

   const QByteArray sendPacket = QByteArrayLiteral("\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x0A\0xC5\x0CD");

   while (true) {
      transmit(port, sendPacket, log);
      do {
        receive(port, log);
      } while (port.waitForReadyRead(3000));
   }
}
```